# How send notification into ms teams user from custom tab

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

I'm designing a custom team tab using React that calls third party API, I need after executing the API successfully, user gets notified . What is the best way to achieve this? I used Bot in my project, but not sure how can I call it from my custom tab class.  I'm aware of the existence of proactive messaging, is it the only way to do it? If it is, a pointer on how to implement it to a custom tab would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to message the user 1-1 (like in the personal app), then proactive messaging is definitely what you need (inside a Team, there are other options), and considering you have the bot already in place that's perfect. The only thing you might be missing are the details required to send the actual proactive message (the best time to get them is when the bot is first installed by the user). In particular, you need ConversationId and ServiceUrl.

With regards the concept of Proactive Messaging, basically once the bot is installed, and you have the required values, you can -send- the message from any backend code at all. That can include, for example, custom tab's backend api. You need to identify the user, which you can do using the Teams `Context` (it's not the safest way but it's the easiest), and then look up the values in your own backend store (e.g. database or whatever) to get the ConversationId and ServiceUrl, then just message the user in your backend.

Comment: Thank you Hilton. We need to implement SSO, and I thought for that purpose we need to have custom tab.So, one of the scenarios is adding a new custom tab into chat conversation, and from that tab, the third party backend API is called , after receiving successful response from the api, notification into current chat conversation needs to be sent from tab's code:
I thought that I can post the message by calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/${context.userObjectId}/chats/${chatId}/messages`
but it didn't work.
It is not a 1-1 messaging, user should just add a custom tab

Comment: I fetched chatId in custom tab class:
 microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
                chatId = context.chatId;
                userId = context.userObjectId
......

Is that the correct way?

Comment: So, you definitely don't need a Tab to get SSO! IF you have a Tab, AND you need SSO, then you want to use "Tab SSO". If you have a BOT and you need SSO, then you should look into BOT SSO. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots

Comment: You are right, thanks for the link, I think, maybe I am in the wrong way, I wanted to have a custom tab , and then calling the third party API from tab's code, after receiving the resposneCode=200, notify the user in the corresponding chat window. I thought that maybe I can just post in the chatId with microsoft graph:
fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/${context.userObjectId}/chats/${chatId}/messages`, ......
In this solution, I don't need bot. what do you think about this way?

Comment: Yes that's also possible, but you can do that with standard proactive messaging, and don't need SSO for that

Comment: sure, glad to help!